# 'saveInBackgroundWithBlock' not working in iOS 7, parse 1.9.1

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, ios7, ios8

In my iOS app I am using Parse service: 
Parse SDK version 1.9.1.

The following block doesn't get executed when I run it on an iOS 7 device. But it works fine in iOS 8/9 devices.

```
[prod saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
   if (succeeded && !error) {
       NSLog(@"Save successful");
   }else {
       NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
   }
}];
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work in iOS 7 (versus iOS 8/9).
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you put this function ? Maybe the enclosing function is not available in iOS7 (e.g. some delegate methods, etc) ?

Comment: @the_critic No its not put in any delegate methods. It is written inside a button click method.

Comment: No errors whatsoever ? Have you tried adding a breakpoint to your enclosing function ?

Comment: @the_critic No errors. I tried with breakpoints, method gets called, this block doesn't gets executed.